# How to center all the layers canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to see all the layers Exact location and size of the yellow square

I want to position all the layers to center width and `top;10px;` inside the yellow rectangle.
all the layers include layerA should be `width:1000px height:500px`

I try to do that In many ways but something Beyond my understanding.

I know it can be done but somting wrong in my code.

I am grateful for any help.

[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zSaQm/3/show/)

my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
<style type='text/css'>
 body   {background-color:black; padding:0; margin:0;                                             }
#layers {position:relative; width:1000px; height:500px; padding:0; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; z-index:1; top:10px; background-color:blue; }//contain all layers
#layerA {position:absolute; width:1000px; height:500px; padding:0; margin:0; z-index:4; background-color:green; border:1px green solid; left:0; top:0;}//background screen show
#layerB {position:absolute; width:1000px; height:500px; padding:0; margin:0; z-index:2; background-color:red; border:1px red solid; visibility:hidden; }//Variable animation hidden
#layerC {position:absolute; width:1000px; height:500px; padding:0; margin:0; z-index:3; background-color:brown; border:1px brown solid; display:none; }//Variable animation hidden
#layerD {position:absolute; width:1000px; height:500px; padding:0; margin:0; z-index:5; background-color:azure;   border:1px azure solid; }//create ball

#pos{top:50px; left:10px; color:white; font-size:16px;}
#status{position;absolute; top:10px; left:10px; color:white; font-size:16px;}
#status1{position;absolute; top:20px; left:10px; color:white; font-size:16px;}
#fps_count {position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 0px; width:150px; font-size: 20px;
            color: white; font-family: 'Happy Sans', cursive; border:1px red solid;}
/* Loading */
#loading {position:relative; width:1000px; height:500px; padding:0; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; top:10px; background:yellow; z-index:1;}
#loading #barCont {width: 400px; height: 20px; position: absolute;
                   top: 50%; left: 50%; margin: -10px 0 0 -200px; background: black;}
#loading #bar {width: 0; height: 20px; position: absolute; left: 0; background: #F3FF67;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="loading">
  <p id="loadText">Loading...</p>
  <div id="barCont"></div>
  <div id="bar"></div>
</div>

<div id="layers">
    <canvas id="layerA" ></canvas>
    <canvas id="layerB" ></canvas>
    <canvas id="layerC" ></canvas>
    <canvas id="layerD" ></canvas>
</div>

<div id="fps_count">71 32 58 FPS</div>
<div id="pos">pos</div>
<div id="status">status</div>
<div id="status1">status1</div>
<script>
var WW = 1400,WH = 700,WTH = 1000,HTH = 500;

var layerA        = document.getElementById('layerA'),//layer background
    CanvasA       = layerA.getContext('2d');
    layerA.width  = 300;//width size of image background
    layerA.height = 150;//height size of image background

var layerB        = document.getElementById('layerB'),//senvich animation hidden
    CanvasB       = layerB.getContext('2d');
    layerB.width  = WW;
    layerB.height = WH; 

var layerC        = document.getElementById('layerC'),//DEFINE layerBVariable it use as a variable
    CanvasC       = layerC.getContext('2d');
    layerC.width  = WW;
    layerC.height = WH;

var layerD        = document.getElementById("layerD"),//createball
    CanvasD       = layerD.getContext('2d');    
    layerD.width  = WW;
    layerD.height = WH;

    CanvasA.clearRect(0,0,300,150);
    CanvasA.fillStyle= 'green';
    CanvasA.fillRect(0,0,300,150);

    CanvasB.clearRect(0,0,WW,WH);
    CanvasB.fillStyle= 'red';
    CanvasB.fillRect(0,0,WW,WH);

    CanvasC.clearRect(0,0,WW,WH);
    CanvasC.fillStyle= 'brown';
    CanvasC.fillRect(0,0,WW,WH);

    CanvasD.clearRect(0,0,WW,WH);
    CanvasD.fillStyle= 'azure';
    CanvasD.fillRect(0,0,WW,WH);        
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "to position all the layers to center width"?  What is the expected result? What do you see instead?

Comment: I want to see all the layers Exact location and size of the yellow square

Comment: To be clear - you want the canvas elements and the yellow layer to be the same size and take up the same position? Essentially covering each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/opherv/AeYhR/)

First, `// comment` is not a valid comment syntax in CSS. This was mucking up your code.
Please use `/* comments */` for CSS inline commments.

Secondly, to position your canvas elements like *I think* I requested, I've included this CSSc code:

```
#layers {position:absolute; width:1000px; height:500px; padding:0; margin-left: -500px; left: 50%; z-index:1; top:10px; background-color:blue; }/*contain all layers*/
#layers canvas{width: 200px;} #layerA {position:absolute; width:1000px; height:500px; top: 0px; left: 0px; padding:0; margin:0; z-index:4; background-color:green; border:1px gre solid; left:0; top:0;}/*background screen show*/
#layerB {position:absolute; width:1000px; height:500px; top: 0px; left: 0px;  padding:0; margin:0; z-index:2; background-color:red; border:1px red solid; visibility:hidden; }/*Variable animation hidden*/
#layerC {position:absolute; width:1000px; height:500px; top: 0px; left: 0px;  padding:0; margin:0; z-index:3; background-color:brown; border:1px brown solid; display:none; }/*Variable animation hidden*/
#layerD {position:absolute; width:1000px; height:500px; top: 0px; left: 0px;  padding:0; margin:0; z-index:5; background-color:azure;   border:1px azure solid; }/*create ball*/
```

To center a 1000px wide absolutely positioned element I've added `left: 50%; margin-left: -500px`. This essentially tells the browser to place the left-most edge of the element at 50% of its container (in this case, the document body), then move it to the left the amount of half of its width in pixels. This allows it to be properly positioned in the center

FYI - I **strongly** suggest for you to use classes instead of IDs here to avoid repeating, unreadable CSS code.